# Flex: assigning events to dynamically created buttons

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, button, settings, externalizing

Thanks to wezzy and the others who helped me out the past couple of days. I've been taking their advice and trying to figure the rest out on my own but I'm stuck again.

I have a txt file structured like this:

```
button1_label
button2_label
button3_label
```

My program creates these 3 buttons at runtime and places them in a group.

```
protected function onLoaded(e:Event):void {
                var myArrayOfLines:Array = e.target.data.split(/\n/);
                var tempBtn:Button;

                for(var i:Number = 0;i < myArrayOfLines.length;i++){
                    var j:Number = i+1;
                    tempBtn = new Button();
                    tempBtn.id = "btn" + i;
                    tempBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(evt:MouseEvent):void{
                        var index:uint = parseInt(evt.currentTarget.id.replace("btn", ""));
                                    //TextArea code will go here

trace(text); // Traces null
                    });
                    tempBtn.label = myArrayOfLines[i];
                    btnArray.push(tempBtn);
                    group.addElement(btnArray[i]);
                }
            }
```

Now what you can see from my code is that I'm attempting to make each button print a string to a textarea. I've structured my new buttons.txt like this:

```
button1_label
"Hello"
button2_label
"Goodbye"
button3_label
"Come again"
```

So what I want to do is have button1 print "Hello". All the lines of the .txt file are pushed into myArrayOfLines. Thanks in advance for any help.

**EDIT**
Full explanation

Sorry I was trying to simplify my question, guess I made it harder to understand. I made a text editor than runs client side, no server. I have a set of buttons that insert predefined phrases into the TextArea Each button has a listener that does myTextArea.insert("sometext"); (but different text for each button. Users have requested the ability to create their own buttons to insert there own strings. I figured I would have a couple og textinputs where a user could define a label, and a String that would be inserted into the textarea on button click. I would write the label to one line, then the String to the next line. Right now I created a buttons.txt file with this format to see if it would work.

**FINAL EDIT: WORKING CODE**

```
public function setupBtns(e:Event):void{
            var file:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("buttons.txt");
            var stream:FileStreamWithLineReader = new FileStreamWithLineReader();
            stream.open(file, FileMode.READ);

            while(stream.bytesAvailable) {
                // this line contains the headers like button1_label etc.
                var label:String;
                // this line contains the string

                if(stream.bytesAvailable) {
                    // this line contains the actual label like "Hello";
                    label = stream.readUTFLine();
                    line = stream.readUTFLine();

                    // strip off the first and last character as they are double quotes
                    line = line.substring(1, line.length-1);

                    var tempBtn:Button = new Button();
                    tempBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnListener);

                    tempBtn.label = label;
                    tempBtn.name = line;
                    btnArray.push(tempBtn);
                    for(var i:Number = 0;i<btnArray.length;i++){
                        group.addElement(btnArray[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }           

        protected function btnListener(e:MouseEvent):void{
            mainTextField.insertText(e.target.name);    
            trace(e.target.name);
        }
```

Comment: It is generally considered appropriate to edit the original question when asking for follow up information.  I'm unclear if this is really a new question or heavily based on the one.  Assuming there is enough content to quantify a new question (I'll let you decide) I removed the 'followup' text to your subject line.

Comment: Sorry about that. I marked the other question's answer as solved prematurely. I wasn't sure if I could still post to that question or not. This is basically the same question but with more detail and changes to the code. Should I go back to the original post?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can deselect the previously selected answer.  If so, it is probably best to deselect the answer and edit the old one.  Things are confusing now that you're getting answers here, though.  I doubt anyone will complain if we leave it.  [But; from a archive perspective; it may bug me that the previous question has an "incorrect/incompletely" answer marked as correct]

Comment: 1. Is your myArrayOfLines correctly filled? Have you traced it? 
2. Why don't you use group.getChildIndex(e.currentTarget) to get the index of your button? 
3. What is btnArray for?

Comment: What is the purpose of this?  What exactly are you trying to accomplish by doing this?  Don't beat around the bush and tell us what's the behavior that your user needs.

Comment: Please see my edit for full explanation

Answer (score 1):

Try this out and let me know how it works out...

**EDIT:**  (try new code below)

```
        protected function onLoaded(e:Event):void {
            var myArrayOfLines:Array = e.target.data.split(/\n/);
            var tempBtn:Button;

            for(var i:Number = 0;i < myArrayOfLines.length;i=i+1){
                var j:Number = i+1;
                tempBtn = new Button();
                tempBtn.id = "btn" + i;
                tempBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(evt:MouseEvent):void{
                        myTextArea.text += '\n' + myArrayOfLines[j];
                    });
                tempBtn.label = myArrayOfLines[i];
                btnArray.push(tempBtn);
                group.addElement(btnArray[btnArray.length-1]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Getting closer but There are still problems. It's still creating a button for every line instead of every second line, So for example it creates Button1 a button called "Hello", where "Hello" should be a property of Button1 and not a separate button. Also when they're clicked the text they display is 'undefined'.

Comment: No luck. Tried it in my for loop, and thought maybe you meant j=i+2 but neither worked. Even tried i=i+2 at the bottom of the loop just for fun :)

Comment: explain what you mean by "didn't work" - it still made a button for each line instead of every other line?

Comment: You'll need to change " group.addElement(btnArray[i]);" to  "group.addElement(btnArray[btnArray.length]);"

Comment: Wouln't group.addElement(btnArray[btnArray.length]); only be if it's outside the loop? Also what I meant by didn't work is that it was still showing a button for each line, and the button's output was still 'undefined'

Comment: No difference. A button is created for every line and output is 'undefined' I don't even know where undefined is coming from.

Comment: I finally got it, going a different route, Please see my edit for the final working code. Hope it helps someone out. Thanks for all the help Nate!

Answer (score 0):

first: don't use anonymous functions as listeners in actionscript - if you yo, you can't remove them later on.

instead use a class method like this:

```
tempBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onMouseClick);

private function onMouseClick(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
  if (evt.currentTarget == button1_label)
  {
     // do sth for btn1
  }
  else if (evt.currentTarget == button2_label)
  {
     // do sth for btn2
  }
  // ...
}
```

**edit**

just saw, that you are using IDs, then just change the above code to sth like this:

```
if (evt.currentTarget.id == "btn1")
```